# What am i missing as i can't override white background while android app initiliazes?

Tags: android, android-activity, background

I have defined android:background="#FF000000" everywhere but i still can not prevent the white background while app launches. (ActionBar at the top, and white background at the bottom)

Is there any other setting that let me change this init-time background color?

Comment: And you're using which theme?

Comment: now i checked: android:Theme.Light (but my app colors are dark :|)

Comment: How about `@android:style/Theme.Translucent` or `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`... ;)

Comment: I couldn't set it to Translucent because i have an ActionBar with Tabs on the main activity ( it throws exception if i set it to Translucent). I tried to set it to Theme.Holo, white background disappeared but this time i saw a dark-greenish gradient instead of white.

Comment: I think i have to create a custom theme with parent="Theme.Holo" an set colorBackground to #FF000000

Comment: Alrighty. Either way, the theme is the thing you'll have to play with I'd say. But I'm not sure it's as easy as setting a colour. I don't recall the exact details but I think there may be `isFloating` and/or `isTranslucent` attributes which might be relevant. Check Android's theme and style definitions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and showing me the reason: Theme. May you add that i have to play with the Theme to fix this issue, i will mark it as the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always also look at the `Theme`s you chose for your App or Application.

Themes/styles set some essential attributes which result in corresponding settings for the `Window` as well; this can go as far as choosing pixel formats (with/without alpha channel).

Another place to look at might be any code that manipulates `LayoutAttributes` or requests `Window` features in you Activity's `onCreate()` but that doesn't sound very likely given what you wrote.